# Assertion error: false Assertion failure: true Assertion failure message: Test failed: text expected to match

Tags: jmeter

My Response Assertion listener states:

```
Assertion error: false
Assertion failure: true
Assertion failure message: Test failed: text expected to match /{
:   "status":true,
:   "data":
:   [
:   :   {
:   :   :   "nDeviceId":67,
:   :   :   "deviceName":"new",
:   :   :   "timeZone":"UTC+5:30"
:   :   }
:   ],
:   "message":"List of devices ",
:   "statusCode":"dms-200-2006",
:   "traceId":"f4721140-8fdd-4af9-9e2d-fb897521c52c"
}/
```

While my response data is :

```
{
:   "status":true,
:   "data":
:   [
:   :   {
:   :   :   "nDeviceId":67,
:   :   :   "deviceName":"new",
:   :   :   "timeZone":"UTC+5:30"
:   :   }
:   ],
:   "message":"List of devices ",
:   "statusCode":"dms-200-2006",
:   "traceId":"f4721140-8fdd-4af9-9e2d-fb897521c52c"
}
```

I want to know how can i tackle the "/" getting added in the starting of my response assertion?

Comment: It would be nice if you explicitely name a language the example was written (javascript probably?), assertion framework and template that was used for matching result. It might be the template is "shown" on the left of the "/" char and in case it is an empty string, you see just a leading "/"

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're using `Matches` pattern matching rule which expects the input to be a [PCRE](https://www.pcre.org/) so you need to escape all the [meta characters](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#meta_chars).

If you want to check the **exact** response you need to switch to use `Equals` mode instead:

[image]

More information: [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps/)